# How to determine, in a service worker, which HTML5 page orginated the fetch request?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Is there a mechanism in a service worker, which I am unaware, which can allow me to know from which page a fetch request is fired from?

Example:
I have an HTML page uploaded to my website at `/aPageUploadedByUser/onMySite/index.html`, I do want to make sure none of the authorization headers gets passed to any fetch request made by `/aPageUploadedByUser/onMySite/index.html` to any source.

If my service worker does somehow know the originating page of this request, I can modulate them for safety.

Comment: Don't allow users to upload arbitrary html pages on your website in the first place. Security and authorisation should depend only on the resource being accessed, not on the origin of the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question (**but with a caveat that this is not a good idea!**), there are two general approaches, each with their own drawbacks:

- The `Referer:` request header is traditionally set to the URL of the web page that made a request. However, [this header may not always be set](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default) for all types of requests.
- A `FetchEvent` has a [`clientId` property](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#fetch-event-clientid), and that value can be passed to [`clients.get()`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#clients-get) to obtain a reference to the `Client` that created the request. The `Client`, in turn, has a `url` property. The caveats here are that `clients.get()` is asynchronous (meaning you can't use its result to determine whether or not to call `event.respondWith()`), and that the URL of the `Client` may have changed in the interval between the request being made and when you read the `url` property.

With those approaches outlined, the bigger problem is that using a service worker in this way is not a safe practice. The first time a user visits your origin, they won't have a service worker installed. And then on follow-up visits, if a user "hard" reloads the page with the shift key, the page won't be controlled by a service worker either. You can't rely on a service worker's `fetch` event handler to implement any sort of critical validation.

Comment: Good heads up though. My target website is a PWA and functions only if the service worker is installed. So hard reload and service worker not present won't be a problem. I will play with clientid and once and come back and mark your answer as correct.